# spread in object definition causing undefined properties in "this"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object which I initialize with bunch of properties in node.js, spreading another object in, and at the end defining a getter.

The problem is the the getter uses `this` and all the properties defined on the object before the spread don't exist on `this`.
If I move the spread to the end or start of the object initialization, it works fine.

```js
const obj = { a: 1 }
const obj2 = { 
  prop: 'a',
 ...obj,
 prop2: 'b',
 get test() { 
   return this.prop + this.prop2 
  }
}


console.log(obj2.test); // 'undefinedb'
```

What can possibly be the reason for that?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using?

Comment: It's working for me: $ node ob -->
ab

Comment: seems to be working in the snippet, as mentioned, must be something about the version of Node etc

Comment: I'm using node 14.16.1

Comment: @dor272 I cannot reproduce with [v14.16.1](https://direct.nodejs.org/download/release/v14.16.1/). Can it be that you oversimplified the example and missed something significant?

Comment: can be, although the change I describe in the original question it's the change that I do and making it work/not to work